# Is there a way in C# to set Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox TopMost = true;

Tags: c#, inputbox

My windows form can sometimes have TopMost set to true. If TopMost is set to true, and the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox opens in the wrong spot it will display behind the form.

I don't want to set the form's TopMost property to false then change it back to true just to get around this. I'd much prefer to check if the form does have TopMost set to true then give the InputBox TopMost as well.

Comment: Why do you use VisualBasic assembly but tag with c#?

Comment: InputBox simply shows a dialog, why not make one? then you can control everything.